# Innodb Engine and Myisam Engine

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

I'm using mysql 5.5 version and using myisam engine for my database. But, Innodb engine not yet disabled. while I execute this command `show variables like '%have%';` ,it returns `have_innodb=yes`. In this case,
can I disable the innodb engine and set zero to all innodb variables is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **Windows**, look for **my.ini** file in your MySQL Server installation directory. For **Linux based OS** look for **my.cnf** in the MySQL Server installation directory.

In that file **un-comment** the line **`skip-innodb`** by removing **`#`** from its beginning.

**Note:** Restart the server for watching changes taking effect.

**EDIT:**
When you have disabled **`Innodb`**, other **`Innodb`** related variables will not be set. You will not be able to access them.

See the screenshot attached first one when InnoDB is disabled, then InnoDB enabled
[image: InnoDB status screenshot]

Hope it helps...

Comment: @shubhanash It only disabled the innodb engine.But, may i disable or set 0 to all innodb parameters

Comment: @dhileepanM Check the edited answer and after disabling Innodb, try running `show variables like "%innodb%"`. It will not show other innodb related variables.

Comment: Check the screenshot attached. I also have MySQL version 5.5.15 running on windows machine. When I disable InnoDB and restart server then I dont get access to innodb related variables.